# Material Table With Parent Form - Input Fields in Footer Result in "No Provider for NgForm" Error When running Unit Test

Tags: jasmine, angular-material, karma-jasmine, angular-forms, angular-material-table

I have a number of child components containing a material table with a parent form (templated) defined in a parent component.  They all work fine and they all pass unit testing except for one that has input fields in the table footer.  When running unit tests on this one I get the NullInjectorError: No provider for NgForm! error.

This is the part of the markup containing the controls that Jasmine is having a problem with:

```
            <ng-container matColumnDef="saturday">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Saturday</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let exception;let i = index;" class="hours">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input min=0  max=23.75 pattern="^(?!0\d)\d+(?:[.](?:25|5|75|0)0*)?$" required #today="ngModel" matInput [(ngModel)]="exception.hours['saturday']" (ngModelChange)="updateTimesheetEntry($event,today,'saturday')" (focus)="focused['saturday'][i]=true" (focusout)="focused['saturday'][i]=false" name="exception-saturday{{i}}">
                        <mat-error #total *ngIf="focused['saturday'][i]">{{getErrorText(today)}}</mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
            </mat-cell>
        <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef class="hours">
                <input type="hidden" max=23.75 name="saturdayTotal" #saturdaytotal="ngModel" [ngModel]="getTotals('saturday')"> 
                <div *ngIf="saturdaytotal.invalid" class="error">
                        {{totalError}}
                </div> 
        </mat-footer-cell>  
        </ng-container>
```

The contents of mat-cell are fine - it's just the input in the footer that causes the test to fail.

Here is the spec file:

```
describe('AttendanceExceptionsComponent', () => {
```

let component: AttendanceExceptionsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture;

beforeEach(async(() => {

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [AppMaterialModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
  declarations: [AttendanceExceptionsComponent],
  providers:[
    {provide : AttendanceService, useValue: { approved : of() } } ,
    {provide : ExceptionService, useValue: { getExceptionTypes : () => { return of(); } } } ,
    {provide : PanelService, useValue: {}},
    {provide : NotificationService, useValue: {}},
    {provide : StateService, useValue: {}},

  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]      
}).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AttendanceExceptionsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

});

I've tried adding NgForm to the providers

```
        {provide : NgForm, useValue: <NgForm>{}},
```

But then I get another error: ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
              formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.

As I've said, this all works fine when I run ng serve, it's just testing that throws these errors & I have no way of bypassing the tests because it's built into our CI build so I am totally stuck!

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by adding the following to the providers in the spec file:

```
    {provide : NgForm, useValue: new NgForm([], [])},
```

I don't know why the behaviour of controls with ngModel in the mat-footer-cell is different to that of those in the  mat-cell but they certainly seemed to be wired up to the form differently.

Comment: De nada, amigo!